# Unable to save record using partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, datamapper

In my rails 3 project, im using DataMapper as the ORM and Haml as the templating language. and have defined one to many association between two models,Car and Image. One car can have many images and an image belongs to one car.

In my Image model, i have the following

```
belongs to: car
```

In my Car model, i have

```
has n, :images
```

In the view for the Car model i have the following:

```
= f.fields_for :images, @car.images do |img|
  = render :partial => "cars/images", :locals => {:f => img}
```

Now, in the view for the images model , i have

```
 = time_select("image", "upload_time")
```

where upload_time is a field in the images table.

But the data is not getting recorded in the images table. What is the correct way to access the fields in the partial ?

Thank You

Comment: What do your unit tests say about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

Add this to you Car model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
```

And your select should be

```
= time_select("image[]", "upload_time")
```

Comment: Eventually, `accepts_nested_attributes_for` only works with ActiveRecord ORM. Datamapper has `dm-accepts_nested_attributes_for` too, but it usually creates dependency problems with existing dm-core.

Comment: Don't use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` then. Just be sure to catch the right parameters and create records for images in the controller. It helps to use `=debug params if Rails.env == 'development'` when working with forms.